# Looking for a new graphics card (HD4850) cooler

Tags: cooling

Alright: The problem: The cooler on my HD4850 stopped working. It doesn't go on automatically, on every bootup I have to manually give it a tap to get it going, and even then it only spins at about... 20% speed I presume.

Now as de cooling elements and heatsinks on the Club3D HD4850 version aren't as good, the card overheats and makes my system crash after a couple of minutes gaming. I can get away with Modern Warfare 2 and such, but games like Mafia 2 and others: No dice :(

So I'm looking for a new cooler. I was looking at the Accelero Twin Turbo Pro today, as I helped a mate install the larger version of it on his HD4870x2, and it works splendidly. Any input on the performance on this system, or other coolers that might be better?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Accelero is a great cooler go for that one.

There is one that I'll be putting on my 5850, but it will work on the 4850, is a combination of:

[Thermalright Spitfire](http://www.thermalright.com/products/index.php?act=data&cat_id=30&id=93)

[Thermalright VRM-R5](http://www.thermalright.com/products/index.php?act=data&cat_id=29&id=105)

But I do believe the VRM-R5 is only for reference models so make sure yours is.